# A database for each category?

Tags: multisite, database

I thought that wp multisite was ok for my idea to have a network with separated databases but I read that the database is shared. So I wonder if there is something to have one backend and a database for each category/site.
I read an old conversation where Multi-DB was mentioned but it seems to be not updated and maybe ot caompatible with a new version of wp.

Comment: Multisite sites don't have separate databases, but they do have separate _tables_. If you need sites with separate databases, why not just set them up as individual installs?

Comment: Because it's a news site with a lot of categories (cities) and a lot of post (160000) and I need to post the same post in multiple categories/sites/cities.